# How to move a cursor to the first character of the current line by a keyboard shortcut

Tags: delphi

Is there a keyboard shortcut to move a cursor to the first character of the current line not to the position 0?

Comment: In which component ? Generally, in multiline edit controls it's the Home key.

Comment: Do you mean inside the IDE source editor?

Comment: @TLama not in components, in the code editor. thanks.

Comment: @UweRaabe yes, in the code editor. thanks.

Comment: Andy's DDevExtensions name it 'extended home'. Press home twice, first puts the caret to line start, second to character. Or the other way around, controllable through an option.

Comment: @Sertac, [`CnPack has it too`](http://i.imgur.com/NwgpCOa.png). I'm using this feature so frequently, that I would assume this being part of the built-in source editor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you have XE8 and/or Castalia installed there is the Smart Home Key feature.

From the [Help](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/How_to_Use_Smart_Keys_%28Castalia%29#How_to_Use_the_Smart_Home_Key):

**How to Use the Smart Home Key**

1. Place the cursor anywhere in the code editor.
2. Press the Home key. The Code Editor moves the cursor to the
   beginning of the line where the cursor was located.
3. If you press the Home key again, the code editor moves the cursor to the beginning of the text.
4. If you press the Home key again, the code editor moves back the cursor to the beginning of the line.

Comment: this is what i want which works in visual studio. i am sorry that i use xe4. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In the IDE editor, with default keyboard shortcuts, use a combination of
`Home` and `Ctrl+RightArrow`.

Comment: because the direct shortcut doesn't work in xe4 i have to use your solution. thanks a lot.